# Found incompatible module node - in which is not supported - create react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, npm, create-react-app

I am running into a problem when I try to install react / babel on my computer. If anyone can help, I would appreciate.

I am running a Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
`node -v`  14.4.0, so the documentation would be okay.
`npm -v` is 6.14.5

The problem is, every time I run the command `npx create-react-app my-app` , I receive this error:

```
Creating a new React app in /home/leni/Desktop/Tests/bla/my-app.

**warning You are using Node "15.0.0-nightly202006043a7a5d7e62"** which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
(node:102555) [DEP0139] **DeprecationWarning: Calling process.umask() with no arguments is prone to race conditions and is a potential security vulnerability**.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
warning You are using Node "15.0.0-nightly202006043a7a5d7e62" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
(node:102590) [DEP0139] DeprecationWarning: Calling process.umask() with no arguments is prone to race conditions and is a potential security vulnerability.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
**error @babel/core@7.9.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module.** **Expected version ">=6.9.0". Got "15.0.0-nightly202006043a7a5d7e62"**
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd /home/leni/Desktop/Tests/bla/my-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting my-app/ from /home/leni/Desktop/Tests/bla
Done.
```

I am sure that I am using node v14.4.0 but every time that I try to create a react project, I encounter failure, any idea in how to solve this? I tried to use **Next.js** as well, but I had the same problem.

Thank you very much for the help.
Leni

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same error. Make sure you don't have a Node app installed through the Ubuntu Software "shop". Deleting it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am still trying to find the best solution but digging on stackoverflow I found this command and it worked fine.

**create-react-app react-app --use-npm**